# Mailmerge from Excel to premade template in Word

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following code to take data from the Excel file "Data" and use it for a mailmerge in a prepare Word template named "Template." I'm new to using VBA in word or Access, so any feedback in these areas is very welcome

```
Sub AccessTransfer()

Dim strPath As String
Dim objAccess As Access.Application
Dim strExcelPath As String
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & lastRow, "M" & lastRow)
strPath = "L:\...\MailMergeTEMPDB.accdb"
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)
objAccess.Visible = False
strExcelPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Set objAccess = New Access.Application
Call objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strPath, False)
objAccess.Visible = False
Call objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acImport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "MailMergeTable", strExcelPath, _
True, Range:="Data!")
Access.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase

Dim wdApp As Object, newDoc As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "L:\...Template.docm"
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Documents.Open strFile, ReadOnly:=False
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Run "Project.Module1.WordMailMerge"
    Kill "L:\....MailMergeTEMPDB.accdb"
End Sub
```

And then Macro called from within Word is:

```
Sub WordMailMerge()
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "L:\...MailMergeTEMPDB.accdb"
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        strFile _
        , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
        WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=strFile;Mode=Read;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=""""" _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `MailMergeTable`", SQLStatement1:="", _
        SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    Windows("AH_MacroMailMergeTemplate").Activate
    ActiveDocument.Close
End Sub
```

I'm also new to using VBA to navigate trough directories, so feedback in this aspect would be appreciated too.

Comment: Apologies. I left out an "End Sub"

Comment: Why do you transfer data from Access database to Excel? You can create Word MailMerge object directly from that database. See this [MSDN documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-table-or-query-as-a-mail-merge-data-source-860ef4bc-e793-4004-8a1b-5c8a34c7e89d)

Comment: Hmm. I did not know that. This changes everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to `Call` anything, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`.

What's this

> ```
> Kill "L:\....MailMergeTEMPDB.accdb"
> ```

Is this closing the access object? Is this deleting the file? Be explicit - `Kill` isn't something you generally want to see in any code.

```
FSO.Deletefile strPath
```